# How do I tell CMake to link the C standard library, not the C++ one?

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a simple C++ file, but I do not want to use the C++ standard library, just the C one.
Can this be done using CMake? Basically disabling access to the c++ headers, and only allowing linking to the C standard.

Comment: Just use the c-compiler to build your files??

Comment: I am using CMake to generate te build files for each platform, calling the compiler directly would defeat the purpose of using cmake

Comment: using the extension `.c` for your files, or using the flag `-x c` maybe

Comment: I'm actually using c++ syntax (classes, polymorphism, ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `target_compile_options(yourprog PRIVATE -nostdinc++)` for clang and GCC based toolchains and /X with the path to its STL headers with msvc